# jmeter Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac https site

Tags: https, proxy, jmeter

I'm new here, I'm having this issue using JMeter proxy while I'm trying to open a site https, it only occurs with the login page, the other pages load correctly, any help? Thanks!

I'm using jmeter proxy and the browser is firefox.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:236)
```

Comment: Please provide the details of browser, you are using with Jmeter proxy?

Also try again after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Hi, yes it is jmeter proxy and the browser is firefox. I use foxyproxy to configure the proxy. Do you have any idea about this problem?. This only happened with the login page, the other pages load correctly. Thanks Vicky

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your jmeter configuration doesn't match your server configuration. This error usually indicates that SSLv3 enabled server is being tested using wrong SSL protocol from JMeter load generator side.

As far as I recall it defaults to TLS and it can be changed i.e. by adding following line to `user.properties` file which resides under /bin folder of your JMeter installation:

```
https.default.protocol=SSLv3
```

Alternatively you can launch JMeter providing this property as a command-line argument to JMeter startup script as follows:

```
jmeter -Jhttps.default.protocol=SSLv3 -n -t your.script.jmx -l your.script.log.jtl
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter Properties and ways to play with them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer my question, I already tried to put that line on the jmeter properties but nothing happened, do you have another idea?. Btw the browser is firefox and I use foxyproxy to configure the proxy.
The other pages doesn't give me that problem, only the login page, so I understand it is related to the encryption of the page like you mentioned before. 

Thanks, Vicky

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get this error while running/executing your test and not while recording the login scenario.

please check the following:

- Click on the HTTP sampler for Login request
- Check the **PORT Number**, since it is an https request it should be generally 443.

Hope this will help.